# Unable to find elements in modal popup using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, modal-dialog, webdriver

I need to confirm a modal popup. I have a form which I fill up and have to move to next page. When I click continue, a modal popup appears asking if the details filled are correct?

There are two button and some other description on it. One button reads cancel and other says `Yes, information is correct.` I tried switching to the modal element by

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);  // there is only one popup
```

However, whatever I do with `webDriver` after that results in `NullPointerException` as no webelement is found.

This is what am trying

```
WebElement modalButtonContainer = AutoUtils.findElementByClassName(modalOverlay, "modalButtonContainer");
WebElement modalButton = AutoUtils.findElementByClassName(modalButtonContainer, "buttonClass");
modalButton.click();
```

But it all results in `NullPointer`. How do I click the `modalButton`?

Comment: Share site url.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` switches to `<iframe>` elements. Here you're talking about the `popup`. This one again depends, if this is a typical `JavaScript` popup invoked with `javascript:alert('popup')` or similar, then

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

is the way to go. Otherwise, if it's some bootstrap popup, then you don't need any switching at all, maybe some `FluentWait` only.

(if it doesn't work, please share the DOM)

Comment: It's not an alert. Have tried, it gives "No Alert present" exception.

Comment: Have you tried NO SWITCHING at all? Add temporarily(!) Thread.sleep(2000) for test before `modalButton.click();`

Comment: Yeah. No Switchin seems like helping.

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck with rest of your test!

Answer (score 0):

As there are two buttons on the pop up, and if both buttons class name is same ('buttonClass')

Better to try identify the button with some other locator either with name or some other unique attribute.

```
WebElement modalButtonContainer = AutoUtils.findElementByClassName(modalOverlay, "modalButtonContainer");
WebElement modalButton = AutoUtils.findElementByName(modalButtonContainer, "Cancel");
                       (or)
WebElement modalButton = AutoUtils.findElementByName(modalButtonContainer, "Yes, information is correct.");
modalButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` doesn't mean `element not found`. It means that you're trying to access an object, which is not yet initialized. Check your stacktrace. It'll show you an exact line, where you've tried to access an uninitialized object. It might be either page object or web element you're interacting with. When you detect an issue, verify that `new` operator is used. Or if you're using `PageFactory`, don't forget about calling `initElements`.